# How to send an email with query output result as attachment from Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a data  into the SSMS table that I need to send it as an email attachment using data factory. any suggestion to set up a pipeline such way so I can query the data from the table and attach that output and send it in the email would be appreciate.

- I tried using logic APP to send an email , I am able to send an email but I was not able to find out the way I can attach the query output data as an attachment in that email , 1st have a lookup activity to get the data from the table then I have used web activity to set the trigger to send an email. inside the web activity I have used Logic app URL , post as method ,
  BODY : { "message" : "@{activity(Lookup1').output}", "DatafactoryName" : "@{pipeline().DataFactory}",      "pipelineName" : "@{pipeline().PipelineName}","receiver" : "@{variables('receiver')}"
- I have declare variable called receiver to store email ids.

Answer (score 0):

To send an Output of lookup activity as an attachment follow the below procedure:

In logic app For the **Send Email (V2)** action, customize how you wish to format the email, using the properties and to add attachment **select `Attachment` from `Add new parameter` dropdown give Attachment name you want and add Attachment Content as `message` from Dynamic content.**

[image]

**For the Body, enter the following JSON:**

```json
{
    "message" : "@{string(activity('Lookup1').output.value)}",
    "dataFactoryName" : "@{pipeline().DataFactory}", 
    "pipelineName" : "@{pipeline().Pipeline}" ,
    "receiver" : "@{pipeline().parameters.receiver}"
}
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I have tried same way you have mentioned, but still getting below error ,
{ "error" : {"code":"InvalidRequestContent","message":"The request content is not valid and could not be deserialized:'After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: P.Path 'message',line2,position 20.'."}} :

Comment: don't go in dynamic content and add the body values in it just simply copy paste the body value in Body It might solve the issue.

Comment: added body value and its working fine, Just curios why it is not working when I add body in dynamic content. Thank You so much for your help

Comment: Also I have I have new requirement that get the files from one drive and load it into Azure Blob Storage. So for this do I have to create a new logic app or I can modified existing logic app that I have adding other Template in it. Please help to on this new requirement as well . Thanks